# subscribing / unsubscribing functions to events with ethersjs

Tags: ethers.js, events, event-handling

I'm trying to subscribe a function to an event and then unsubscribe it later on.

Having a lot of difficulty with provider.off(event, listener) because i can't seem to get a listener object that I can actually reference.

I know i have the option of doing removeAllListeners(), but in this case i have multiple listeners on the same event, and I want to kill a specific one, not all of them.

here's the code for the listener:

```
    this.provider.on('block', async () => {
        await this.stageUpdateListener()
    })
```

this works as a listener, but i can't reference it specifically since it's an anonymous function, and printing provider.listeners() results in

```
[AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
```

An alternative that seems apparent is just passing in the function:

```
this.provider.on('block', this.stageUpdateListener)
```

However, this ultimately fails because it cannot access the context of 'this'. This does create a block listener that I can use:

```
[AsyncFunction: stageUpdateListener]
```

and i can successfully kill the listener by referencing the function name i passed in, but its not much good if the functionality isnt there

Lastly, i tried binding my function to 'this' upon passing it in:

```
this.provider.on('block', this.stageUpdateListener.bind(this))
```

The listener was functional, but when i went to print the listeners, I got:

```
[Function: bound stageUpdateListener] AsyncFunction
```

which again I don't know how to reference using provider.off()

Would really appreciate any ideas